# Uber dropoff location using Android deeplinks

Tags: android, location, uber-api, deeplink

I'm trying to set the dropoff location for rides via a deeplink from my application to Uber's app.
Right now my format is as follows:

```
uber://?action=setPickup&client_id=<REDACTED>&product_id=db9ab22a-f330-4ab1-b141-e845e9c5a26f&pickup=my_location&dropoff[latitude]=-33.458054&dropoff[longitude]=-70.664207&dropoff[nickname]=Beaucheff+851+ab
```

The problem is that dropoff locations don't match the intended ones. In fact, by varying the latitude and longitude, dropoff location matches to apparently random locations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FOUND THE SOLUTION! The Uber app parses numbers in the device's locale. In the case of the device I'm doing tests on, it's set to spanish, so numbers should be converted to string as `-33,458054` and `-70,664207`.